# XPath for Specifc Tag Under Parent

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd, elementtree

Afternoon. I am trying to parse metadata from and xsd file. I would like to parse the metadata from all the element tags, for each of the parent tags. For instance for the `Speed_Detail` tag below I would like to collect all the data associated with the child `element` attributes. Assume parents are on the same level.

```

```
<xsd:element name="SpeedDetails">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Header" type="global:HeaderInfoType"/>
                <xsd:element name="SpeedUnitOfMeasure" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element name="TileId" type="xsd:long" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsd:element name="Route" type="speed:RouteType"></xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsd:element name="Segment" type="speed:SegmentType"></xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
```

```

I know I can access all the elements via `"//{ns}element".format(ns)` but that gives all elements in the entire tree.

I have been trying to gather the elements with something like `".[@name='{}']*/{}element".format(name,ns)`. I can not get the xpath to work because I keep getting an `invalid predicate error`. Could someone explain why this is the case? And how you would write the correct xpath? Please add your thought precess.

Comment: Questions are encouraged to provide a [Minimum Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), try to improve yours since it's hard to answer without code (python in this case?).

Answer (score 0):

What is the `{}` you keep using in your xpaths? that is not valid xpath. To add to that namespaces (the `xsd:` part) are usually ignored in xpath parsers.

So in python with `lxml` package I got perfectly fine results:

```
>>> tree.xpath('//sequence/element/@name')
['Header', 'SpeedUnitOfMeasure', 'TileId', 'Route', 'Segment']
```

Comment: That is just string formatting notation in python. I wasn't able to get matched tags if I excluded the name space. Can you explain sequence in this case?

Comment: sequence is the node that contains all of the element nodes.

Comment: Ha okay that sound of been obvious. Ill give the lxml package a try.